# How to change the values of days in DatePickerDialog

Tags: view, properties, calendar, field, datepickerdialog

I'd like the DatePickerDialog to show a number of some events/arrangemenmts I've planned in the day field additionally. What I mean. In the default calendar view we can see a month name and from 28 to 31 days for that month, like: **November 1, 2, 3...** And I want to see: **November 1, 2 (4 events), 3 (2 events) ...** or just **November 1, 2 (4), 3 (2) ...** How can I realize that? How can I get access to those days' layout property?